# Find last record from distinct by EmpID in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in which I have EMPID column. In this table I have multiple row with same EMPID. Now I want to get last row of distinct EmpID. Please find below table data. And I want to result of Row with ID 3,5 and 7 with all column.

[image]

I want result as below :

[image]

I try with below query but is is not working.

```
SELECT ID,
       EmpID,
       Salary,
       Leave,
       TakenLeave,
       field1,
       field2,
       field3
FROM   Table_2
GROUP  BY ID,
          EmpID,
          Salary,
          Leave,
          TakenLeave,
          field1,
          field2,
          field3
```

Comment: `select * from (select row_number() over(partition by EmpID ....) as rn,* from.. )a where rn = 1`

Comment: please post expected result as text

Comment: Even after the above guy commenting to post the expected result in text format you have posted it as image.. -1

Comment: Sry Pdrp and TheGameiswar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a row_number partition by EmpId and order by Id desc.

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
    select rn = row_number() over(
        partition by EmpId
        order by Id desc
    ), *
    from [your_table_name]
)
select ID, EmpID, Salary, Leave, TakenLeave, field1, field2, field3 from cte
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
TOP 1 WITH TIES 
ID, EmpID, Salary, Leave, TakenLeave, field1, field2, field3 
FROM [TABLE_NAME]
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmpId ORDER BY Id DESC)
```

Comment: @TanjimRahman - ha thank you ;) . I learned it from the great Gordan

Comment: All hail the @Gordon Linoff.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code;

```
    select ID, EmpID, Salary, Leave, TakenLeave, field1, field2, field3
  from (select ID,
               EmpID,
               Salary,
               Leave,
               TakenLeave,
               field1,
               field2,
               field3 row_number() over(partition by EmpID order by id desc) as que
          from table_2)
 where que = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from myTable
where id in 
(
  select max(id) from myTable group by empId
);
```

Inner SQL selects max(id) per empId and outer select selects the rows having those Ids.